# SMS sending in WebAPI with Samsung Gear S

Tags: sms, tizen

Has anyone found a working example for integrating SMS in an app into a Samsung Gear S using the WebAPI?

I found two examples for tizen, but none of them worked with the Gear S. With minor adaptations they look like this:

First try:

```
function sendSMS(smsno)
{
    if (bDebug)
        alert("Versuche SMS (sendSMS) zu senden an " + smsno);
    smsnumber = smsno;
    try
    {

        var appControl = new tizen.ApplicationControl(
                'http://tizen.org/appcontrol/operation/compose', 'sms:'
                        + smsnumber);

        tizen.application.launchAppControl(appControl, null, function()
        {
        }, function(e)
        {
            alert("SMS konnte nicht gesendet werden: " + e.message);
        },
        {
            onsuccess : function()
            {
            },
            onfailure : function(er)
            {
                alert("SMS konnte nicht gesendet werden: " + er.message);
            }
        });
    }
    catch (e)
    {
        alert("http://tizen.org/appcontrol/operation - " + e.message);
    }
}
```

Second try:

```
// Define the success callback.
function messageSent(recipients)
{
    if (bDebug)
        alert("The SMS has been sent");
}

// Define the error callback.
function messageFailed(error)
{
    alert("The SMS could not be sent " + error.message);
}

// Define service error callback.
function serviceErrorCB(error)
{
    alert("Cannot get messaging service " + error.message);
}

// Define the success callback.
function serviceListCB(services)
{
    try
    {
        if (services.length > 0)
        {
            var msg = new tizen.Message("messaging.sms",
            {
                plainBody : "Hilferuf von Nummer: " + smsnumber + ": "
                        + vorname + " " + nachname + ": " + adresse,
                to : [ smsnumber ]
            });
            // Send request
            services[0].sendMessage(msg, messageSent, messageFailed);
        }
    }
    catch (e)
    {
        alert("serviceListCB Problem - " + e.message);
    }
}


function sendSMS_tizen(smsno)
{
    if (bDebug)
        alert("Versuche SMS zu senden an " + smsno);
    smsnumber = smsno;
    try
    {
        tizen.messaging.getMessageServices("messaging.sms", serviceListCB,
                serviceErrorCB);
    }
    catch (e)
    {
        alert("tizen.messaging nicht definiert- " + e.message);
    }
}
```

Unfortunately the Samsung documentation is very unspecific on this part.

ANy ideas welcome!

Comment: In the Gear S one can find that com.samsung.message.appcontrol.compose is defined (checking with tizen.application.getAppsInfo(onListInstalledApps);. But there is no documentation available how to use it. Has anyone an idea on that feature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both solutions are from Mobile profile. It will not work on Gear S. Unfortunately now there is now way to send sms from web api on Gear S. That is why there is no documentation on this ;)

Comment: Ok, thanks. Means developing a native app for Gears S for sending SMS.

Comment: I have another bad news: you can't write native apps on Gear S. SDK does not support this (native is only for mobiles) - I suggest trolling on Tizen forums ;)

Comment: Yes meanwhile I realised that too. Too bad.

Comment: What I really wonder is that the Gear S has a the "Message" app, which allows sending SMS. Maybe there is a way sending an SMS using the builtin messagingapp?

Comment: did you find a way to use the builtin app?